# Count multiple fields

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a table called `reservations`. I'd like to count all `firstName` and `guestFirstName` fields.

I've tried:

```
$records = $dbh->query('SELECT count(firstName, guestFirstName) from reservations')->fetchColumn;
```

This gives me an error. How can I count all `firstName, guestFirstName` records?

Comment: Your counting from table reservations. Are there some rows that have null values for firstname or null values for guestFirstName?

Comment: Is this a view? If you want to count the number of rows count(*) works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
$query =  'SELECT count(firstName) + count(guestFirstName) as total ' . 
                 'FROM reservations';
$result = $dbh->query($query)->fetch();

echo $result['total']
```

SQL Fiddle Validating this: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/42bad/2

SQL's [`COUNT()`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_count.asp) function does not count `NULL` values.

*Thanks for the help to @ChaotiCc*

Comment: Thanks for the help. This seems to only count the firstName field, not the guestFirstName. Do I need to add the two together somewhere?

Comment: I believe this counts them both. I only concatenate the string in several rows, because it's quite long. Have you tried it out ?

Comment: I did try it and it returns the count of just firstName

Comment: You should do 2 `fetchColumn`s, since the counts are stored in two separate columns. Or you could just do a classic `$data = $dbh->query($query)->fetch();` and then use `$data['count_firstname']` and `$data['count_guestname']`.

Comment: gotcha, thanks. I just thought there was a way to count both at once. Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by counting both at once? If you want to add them, you can use `COUNT(firstName) + COUNT(guestFirstName) AS total`.

Comment: @ChaotiCc that's what I'm looking for. Now, how do I exclude NULL from either firstNmae of guestFirstName? Thanks!

Comment: NULL values are not counted by MySQL's `COUNT()` function.

Comment: @ChaotiCc - strange. I see the SQLFiddle working properly, but when I return the values, NULL is counted.

Comment: @relentless Strange indeed. Could it be that what you have in your database is `"NULL"` (the string) instead of `NULL` (the 'object', or whatever you'd call this...)?

Comment: @ChaotiCc - For some reason the example above counted `NULL`. I broke it out into two queries and added the values in php. Works now. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You need to `count()` each column, change as follow

```
'SELECT count(firstName) as total_firstname, count(guestFirstName) as guest_firstname from reservations'
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. This seems to only count the firstName field, not the guestFirstName. Do I need to add the two together somewhere?

Comment: @relentless How do you print them? I gave them an alias for better use

Comment: I just `echo`ed `$records`

Comment: @relentless try `echo $records['total_firstname'];` and `echo $records['guest_firstname'];`